# TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: database, service, port, listener, oracle19c

I have issue with LISTENER so I can't start listener with :

```
>lsnrctl status LISTENER

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-MAR-2022 16:07:04

Copyright (c) 1991, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521)) TNS-12541: TNS:no listener  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error   TNS-00511: No listener    64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

Same error with the lsnrctl reload

When I try to restart it from services windows I have the issue :services on local computer started and stopped
As mentioned in the Snape below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZTkc.png)

This is listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\instantclient_19_8\NETWORK\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER_UBIX =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ubix)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c)
      (SID_NAME = ubix2)
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER_UBIX = C:\app\e5665551

SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_LISTENER_UBIX = TRUE

LISTENER_UBIX =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EMEA-TUN-LP0872.FNFIS.com)(PORT = 1521))
  )
```

and the tnsnames file :

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\E5665551\product\19.3.0\dbhome19c\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.



ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
UBIX =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EMEA-TUN-LP0872.FNFIS.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = UBIX)
    )
  )
LISTENER_UBIX =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EMEA-TUN-LP0872.FNFIS.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

and the log file:

```
LISTENER for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production 
Version 19.10.0.0.0

Message 459 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
Message 279 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
Message 509 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
Message 510 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL

Message 1081 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
Message 1074 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
Message 1050 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

I ask if the problem with security update my block the service of listener ?

```
>sc.exe query OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerORACLE19C

SERVICE_NAME: OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerORACLE19C
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I try to start it by the command line :

```
sc start OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerORACLE19C
```

also with killing the service

```
taskkill /pid 94196 /F
```

THE service still stuck on STOPPED it's the same issue please any help ?

Comment: The status is just telling you what you already know. You need to investigate why the listener service stops - look for the log files and see what they tell you. I imagine there's either an error in the listener config, or it refers to a fixed IP address that no longer applies to your PC, or similar.

Comment: @AlexPoole the LISTENER it's at BEFORE restart my machine it's correctly work now in the trace file I have this message :Message 459 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL

Comment: Please add that kind of info to the question. That sounds like your environment isn't set up properly and the service doesn't have the ORACLE_HOME, PATH or TNS_ADMIN set correctly, maybe. Not sure the best way to do that in Windows. And it's off-topic really, you might be better of deleting this ask asking on dba.stackexchage.com, but with more details about your installation and environment and the log entry.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks now i add all details tnsnames file and listener file also the log

Comment: any update please